# Is there a map with the most popular natural attractions on it?

Tags: europe, online-resources, road-trips, maps, central-europe

I'm looking for an online map covering central Europe (mainly France, Switzerland, Germany, Italy and Austria), which has on it the most popular **natural** attractions (lakes, mountains, scenic roads etc...).
Specifically this is for planning a road trip that I'm about to start from Basel, and I need to decide in which direction to drive. I am not interested in cities, only natural attractions.

BTW if you know about maps of this sort covering other parts of the world, this could be useful for other travelers.

Answer (score 7):

UNESCO [World Heritage Center](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/) provides a list with a map. Square bullets denote cultural heritage whereas round bullets denote natural heritage.

Unfortunately, not many natural attractions are listed there.

Comment: Very nice - thank you!
Unfortunately, as you say, the list of attractions is insufficient. However I'm starting to worry that nothing better will be found.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the [FunTouristAttractions](http://www.funtouristattractions.com/rm/europe-attractions-map/1) map of Europe - but again, not many natural attractions on it.